# MQTT.js doesn't work with a node cluster - Connection closed

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt

I am implementing a cluster node, however in my file I import an mqtt file, which creates an mqtt client. However when I start the file it doesn't work, it closes the connection and gives me this error:
[image]

cluster file:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const  os = require ("os");

const cpuCount = os.cpus().length;
console.log(`The total number of CPUs is ${cpuCount}`);


console.log(`Primary pid=${process.pid}`);
cluster.setupPrimary({
  exec: __dirname + "/app.js",
});


for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
  cluster.fork();
}
cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
  console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} has been killed`);
  console.log("Starting another worker");
  cluster.fork();
});
```

mqtt.js file:

```
//------- MQTTT --------//

const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const queryFunction = require("./utilities/queryFunction")
const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://greenenergyhomes.uniupo.click", {clientId: "Archiver"});

const topic = ["event/greenenergy/+", "desc/greenenergy/+"]

client.on('connect',() => {
  console.log("connessione con il broker MQTT stabilita");
  client.subscribe(topic, console.log);
  
});



client.on('message',(topic, message) => {
    console.log(`message: ${message}, topic: ${topic}`);
    const msgJSON = JSON.parse(message);

    const params = topic.split("/");
    console.log(params)
    switch(params[0]){
      case 'event':
        queryFunction.updateVal(msgJSON, params[3]);
        break;
      case 'desc':
        console.log("desc in MQTT")
        queryFunction.setVal(msgJSON, params[2])
        break
    } 

  });


module.exports;
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Client ids must be globally unique across all clients connected to a broker.

All the instances you have here will be using `Archiver` which means that only the last one to connect will survive, because the MQTT spec says that when a new client connects with the same client ID it must kick the old one off.